# How to control lightsail costs and determine source of costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

Below is a screenshot of my lightsail instance :

[image]

As can see the costs have risen considerable over the past few days.

Reading the billing section of https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/ I don't sections of how to pin point the reasons for this cost increase. I've a MySql instance installed on the box that is adding approx 100 rows of data to a table containing 10 columns every 5 minutes. But certainly does not exceed as per the plan :

"
Every single Lightsail plan also includes a healthy amount of free IN and OUT data transfer. For example, using the cheapest Lightsail bundle you can send and receive up to 1 TB of data to the Internet within the month, at no extra charge.
"

Also I've installed a scheduled task which requests data from 5 server endpoints.

How to pin point the source of the service charges ?

Update :

Viewing costs by hourly breakdown instead of by day will assist in pinpointing the costs overrun. Is this option available ? On the cost explorer dashboard there does not appear to be any option to reduce the granularity costs based on time ?

Comment: Group your costs by service. Generally - play with the cost explorer. You can use the filters on the right hand side as well.

Comment: @Tim please see update.

Answer (score 1):

The information is right there in your graph.

For all days (September 1 to October 1), you were charged:

- EUW2-BundleUsage:0.5GB
- EUW2-DiskUsage

This looks like 2x 500 MB instances + disk in eu-west-2 region (London).

On September 28, you launched another 2x Lightsail instances:

- EU-BundleUsage:4GB
- EU-BundleUsage:1GB

So a 1GB instance and a 4GB instance in eu-west-1.

On September 29, another Lightsail instance was launched:

- EU-BundleUsage:4G

So another 4GB instance in eu-west-1.

My guess is that your "mystery usage" is in the eu-west-1 region (Ireland). Probably you (or someone) launched some instances in the Ireland region without realizing it and/or forgot about them.

Comment: thanks for this, please see question update.